# How to create a bar that stays on top when scrolling?

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

I'm trying to create a div that stays fixed on top when a user scrolls down and when he scrolls back up, goes back to the original position.

I need this exact same behaviour that 9gag offers -> http://9gag.com/gag/293756

Thanks!

Comment: If you need the *exact* same behaviour, have you checked out the source code?

Answer (score 4):

Do the following:

1. Create a [scroll event handler](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/) on the `$(window)`.
2. In this event handler, check if the user has scrolled lower than the top of the element you always want in view.  You can use [offest](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) and [scrollTop](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) methods to do this.
3. If yes, set the element to `position: fixed` with `top: 0`.  You may also need to adjust the left attribute, depending on your layout.
4. If no, set the element to `position: static`.

Comment: Have you tried out anything yet?  Give it a go at http://jsfiddle.net.  If you get stuck, I'll help.

Answer (score 4):

Use the Jquery Waypoints plugin: http://imakewebthings.github.com/jquery-waypoints/

Extremely easy to implement.

Answer (score 1):

The code that creates exactly the same behavior as 9gag.com:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<!-- tags html, header, body, divs, anything -->

<div id="post-control-bar" class="spread-bar-wrap">
    <div class="spread-bar" style="width:600px">
        Facebook button, Twitter button, anything...
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.onscroll = function()
{
    if( window.XMLHttpRequest ) {
        if (document.documentElement.scrollTop > 173 || self.pageYOffset > 173) {
            $('post-control-bar').style.position = 'fixed';
            $('post-control-bar').style.top = '0';
        } else if (document.documentElement.scrollTop < 173 || self.pageYOffset < 173) {
            $('post-control-bar').style.position = 'absolute';
            $('post-control-bar').style.top = '';
        }
    }
}
</script>

<!-- content, footer, anything -->
```